# redmine ldap authentication fail

Tags: ldap, redmine

I'm not succeeding in LDAP authentication with Redmine. Here follows the description of what I've done:

I've installed Bitnami Redmine on Centos 6.7 and trying to authenticate against AD on MS Windows server 2012.

```
Environment: Redmine version 3.1.1.stable
Ruby version 2.0.0-p647 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version 4.2.4
Environment production
Database adapter Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion 1.6.11
  Git 1.7.1
  Filesystem

Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

This is my LDAP configuration on Redmine:

```
Name: geo-AD
Host: geo-dc.geo.net
Port 389 LDAPS: No
User: ldapuser
DN Base: DC=geo-dc,DC=geo,DC=net
LDAP filter: (objectClass=*)
on the fly: yes
Connection attribute: sAMAccontName
Name: givenName
Surname: sn
Mail: mail
```

The test is working fine, but when I try to authenticate I always get

> invalid password

I traced the authentication phase with Wireshark and I've seen the following:

There is a request from the redmine host to the AD server asking for the following attributes:

- dn
- givenName
- sn
- mail

The AD server answer with "no such object" and the authentication stops. I've removed `givenName`, `sn` and `mail` from the LDAP configuration window and the request for DN is still there and cause the failure.

I've checked the AD schema and there is no attribute named "dn".

Any idea why Redmine ask for this during authentication and if there is a way to change this behaviour?

Here follows the LDAP query and LDAP response. 
`192.168.1.244` is the Centos server with Redmine, `192.168.1.240` is MS Server 2012 with AD.

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info

72 28.269126319   192.168.1.244         192.168.1.240         LDAP     237    searchRequest(2) "DC=geo-dc,DC=geo,DC=net" wholeSubtree
```

Frame 72: 237 bytes on wire (1896 bits), 237 bytes captured (1896 bits) on interface 0

Lightweight Directory Access Protocol

```
LDAPMessage searchRequest(2) "DC=geo-dc,DC=geo,DC=net" wholeSubtree

    messageID: 2

    protocolOp: searchRequest (3)

        searchRequest

            baseObject: DC=geo-dc,DC=geo,DC=net

            scope: wholeSubtree (2)

            derefAliases: neverDerefAliases (0)

            sizeLimit: 0

            timeLimit: 0

            typesOnly: False

            Filter: (&(&(objectClass=*)(objectClass=*))
(sAMAccountName=mlavagna))

                filter: and (0)

                    and: (&(&(objectClass=*)(objectClass=*))
(sAMAccountName=mlavagna))

                        and: 3 items

                            Filter: (objectClass=*)

                                and item: present (7)

                                    present: objectClass

                            Filter: (objectClass=*)

                                and item: present (7)

                                    present: objectClass

                            Filter: (sAMAccountName=mlavagna)

                                and item: equalityMatch (3)

                                    equalityMatch

                                        attributeDesc: sAMAccountName

                                        assertionValue: mlavagna

            attributes: 4 items

                AttributeDescription: dn

                AttributeDescription: givenName

                AttributeDescription: sn

                AttributeDescription: mail

    [Response In: 73]

    controls: 1 item

        Control

            controlType: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.319 (pagedResultsControl)

            criticality: False

            SearchControlValue

                size: 126

                cookie: <MISSING>
```

No.     Time           Source                Destination               Protocol

74 28.269493413   192.168.1.244         192.168.1.240         TCP

Lightweight Directory Access Protocol

```
LDAPMessage searchResDone(2) noSuchObject (0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:

'DC=geo,DC=net'

) [0 results]

    messageID: 2

    protocolOp: searchResDone (5)

        searchResDone

            resultCode: noSuchObject (32)

            matchedDN: DC=geo,DC=net

            errorMessage: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 
(NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:\n\t'DC=geo,DC=net'\n

    [Response To: 72]

    [Time: 0.000264030 seconds]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an "ou" (organizational unit) in LDAP? For example, if your users are under ou=People, your redmine DN Base might look like this:

```
DN Base: ou=People,DC=geo-dc,DC=geo,DC=net
```

Comment: No, I don't have ou defined in LDAP.